# jQuery validation wont fire for dropdown/select lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Yes this might be a duplicate of a million other questions like it, but for me it still doesnt work.
According to the jQuery validation documentation, simply having the first default item with an empty value (value=""), and the class "required" is enough. But it refuses to work correctly.
I have everything set up correctly, and it works fine on checkboxes, radiobuttons, text inputs no problem at all, but select lists? Nope.

Here is a simple example:

```
<select class="required" id="dayDropdown" data-bind="'value': StudentBaseData.day">
    <option value="">Dag</option>
</select>
<select class="required" id="monthDropdown" data-bind="'value': StudentBaseData.month">
    <option value="">Måned</option>
</select>
<select class="required" id="yearDropdown" data-bind="'value': StudentBaseData.year">
    <option value="">År</option>
</select>
```

Three dropdownlists, all required. Right here, the odd thing is ONLY the first select validates. The other two are ignored. Further down the page i have two more select lists that refuses any kind of validation.

Here is where i initiate the validation plugin:

```
$(function(){
    $.metadata.setType("attr", "validate");
    $("#StudentsForm").validate({
        ignore: ""
    });
});
```

And i force trigger the validation when the form is submitted:

```
$('#updateProfileButton').click(function subscribe() {
    if($("#StudentsForm").valid()=== true){ //force trigger validation
        // do stuff
    } else { // if jquery validation fails
        // TODO
    }
});
```

And like i said, it works for everything BUT select lists.

If it matters, the select lists are automatically populated by two javascript functions (filling out dates etc.), but the initial default value is set like i have shown above. The strange thing is it works for the first select box, and thats it.

I have searched and searched and i have never found anyone with the same problem.

PS: The "data-bind" is from knockout.js.

Comment: Just an FYI, `""` is not `null` but an empty string.

Comment: Also, `if($("#StudentsForm").valid()=== true)` is better written `if($("#StudentsForm").valid())`.

Comment: Yeah it's an empty string, i forgot, but it doesnt change my explanation. I have edited my post though.
Also putting in "=== true" is for me, simpler as it is more explanatory as to what is going on. Either method works fine.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you replace "Måned" with "Maned" and "År" with "Ar"?  I wonder if for some reason the validation is tripping up on Å/å.

Comment: Just tried it, sadly it doesnt help, but it was a good point. But i cant imagine that being the error to begin with.

Comment: Actually, I'm glad that didn't fix it.  I would be disappointed if it didn't support such characters.

Comment: seems to be fine http://plnkr.co/edit/Lb04IeTxHZlSu6jfYqcB?p=preview

Comment: FDL: What the heck, it seems to be working now :S This makes no sense at all. Technically, giving the select lists a name attribute should make no difference for jquery validator, but everything seems to work now. I have to test a bit more to be 100% sure.

Comment: Added it as an answer so you can accept after you've tested and confirmed it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `name` attribute to your dropdowns. This should fix the problem where you only see the first dropdown being shown as invalid.

Comment: Well from the looks of it, it works after doing a bit of testing. Thank you very much for the help. It's always good to have a new set of eyes take a look at it. But it is odd, because having a "name" attribute is not a requirement for jquery validation to work. Why it is needed here, i do not know, but it works.